# What does ( ) = D.S.x mean?

Tags: piano, notation, repeats

As shown in the second bar of the third complete system (fourth system on the page), I guess it tells me to play like this on first/second time or something.

What is the name of notation? I searched Del Segno but it doesn’t seems right.

[image: Score excerpt]

Comment: To help future people searching for this same question, please include the title of the piece.

Comment: Notice there's double the beats in that measure, a strong hint :-) that you play either the first group *or* the group inside the parentheses.

Comment: D.S. means "dal segno" (note the spelling), but knowing that won't be particularly helpful here.  This notation is idiosyncratic, nonstandard, unusual, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that the very first time that measure is played, it's played with the non-parenthesized notation. On any subsequent visits to that measure, it's played according to the parenthesized notation.

There's no special name for this instruction, but it serves a similar purpose to writing separate "endings":

```
X: 1
T: First and second "endings"
M: 4/4
K: Db clef=bass middle=D
L: 1/8
G,G- G3/2A,/2- A, A2 F |1 F,F- F3/2B,/2- B,3E ||2,3,4  F,F- F3/2B,/2- B,4 ||
```

Comment: Personally, I would prefer the typesetter to have written two Bass Clef lines for those measures (one above the other),  with the "D.S.x" marking in front of the extra staff.

Comment: What do the D S and x stand for?

Comment: @AakashM "D.S." stands for "Dal Segno" (a type of repeat indicator); the "x" stands for the number of times the "D.S" indication (elsewhere in the music) has been encountered. So the "D.S.x" means "play these notes each time you are following a D.S. repeat indication."

Comment: I would have read it the other way around, the "X" means don't play (as in "cross out") on the D.S.

Comment: @Duston So you'd play the parenthetical part first time, and the non-parenthetical part on the D.S.?

Comment: @Aaron No, what I meant was to omit the part in parens on the D.S., but looking again, I see that's wrong.  After counting the beats, I agree you play the non-paren part the first time and the paren part on the D.S.

Comment: Have you ever seen this sort of notation before?  I have not.  I would be less surprised to see a third staff of two measures' duration showing the alternate left hand part.